# Why does the d orbital size decreases on addition of electrons?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, orbitals

In *Concise Inorganic Chemistry* by JD Lee (4th edition; adapted by Sudarshan Guha), on page 80 under section 3.7 "The Extent of d-orbital Participation in Molecular Bonding" it is given:

> A second factor affecting the size of d orbitals is the number of d orbitals occupied by electrons. If only one 3d orbital is occupied on an S atom, the average radial distance is $2.46$Å, but when two 3d orbitals are occupied the distance drops to $1.60$Å.

I wish to know the reason why the size of the d orbital drops when additional electrons are added. I think this is counter-intuitive since on addition of an extra electron the interelectronic repulsions increases and confining them to a small volume increases overall energy of the system thereby making it unstable. So, I think the orbital size must increase, but it is happening the opposite way.

Kindly explain the above-mentioned concept.

Comment: Jan's answer below is spot on but I think the author borrowed the same logic from why atomic radii decreases as you move across a period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much to explain because the concept is wrong. There is no sulphur compounds in which the 3d orbitals (remember: they have an energy level similar to 4s) are involved in bonding in any noteworthy way, shape or form.

From what I believe I may remember about the outdated concept, ‘one d orbital’ refers to cases like $\ce{SO3^2-}$ with sulphur in the $\mathrm{+IV}$ oxidation state while ‘two d orbitals’ would refer to e.g. $\ce{SO4^2-}$ or an oxidation state of $\mathrm{+VI}$. In the Lewis formalism, the answer is easily deduced if you draw octet-abiding structures: $\ce{SO3^2-}$ will include a formal single positive charge on sulphur while in $\ce{SO4^2-}$ sulphur has a formal double positive charge. The higher an oxidation state, the more contacted an atom becomes.

A more correct answer would elaborate on ($\mathrm{sp}^n$-type, formed only by sulphur’s s and p atomic orbitals) molecular orbitals and the increasing number of electronegative substituents that need to bond to the central sulphur, reducing its charge density and leading to the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the first paragraph, you have said the concept of d orbital participation in sulphur compounds is incorrect. I understood the reason you have mention in the same paragraph. In the last paragraph, you have said (or what I understood based on your answer and what was given in my book as the first reason for the participation of d orbitals in bonding) increase in electronegative substituents causes d orbitals to contract in size thereby causing a fall in energy similar to that of the orbitals participating in bonding.

Comment: If the concept is incorrect why must it have an explanation? Sorry to irritate you by this large comment. Kindly reply when you find time.

Comment: @Intellex You misunderstood me. The calculated molecular orbitals for these types of compounds are made up of over 99 % s and p contributions. With these $\mathrm{sp}^n$-type orbitals, you can do the electronegativity discussion and reduce their energies/contact them. While the outer d orbitals as well as any other highly virtual orbitals will also contact and be lowered in energy, this has no effect on the bonding situation as the *difference* between the energies remains almost the same. The charge density mentioned is sulphur’s overall charge density across all (including core) orbitals.